# Java, Eclipse: Finding Files ending in a certain pattern/extension/whatever

Tags: java, eclipse, file, directory

So basically I am using Eclipse to program in java and I have a workspace where my project folder is. By default, when no directory is specified when writing a file (e.g. "./file.txt"), the file gets saved in the Project folder/directory.

Now, what I want to do is find a file or files in my project directory that ends in a certain parttern/extension/whatever (e.g. "le.txt"), which would probably return true or a list of the files names that end that way (depending on how the method is written) in which probably the file "file.txt" from the first example would be included.

I found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-find-files-with-certain-extension-only/) in the internet and was attempting to use it as a guideline to make my own code, but found a few problems hard to solve:

1. The code includes directory, which in my case it doesn't, I just
   mean to use the default project directory. **How to say to the program to directly look for files in the project directory?**
2. I see the code being very complicated. I remember a friend doing something similar and it wasn't as complicated as in the code in the link. Although this is not really all that important, it would be great if someone could tell me a simpler workaround to the way it's done in the link.

Thank you, and I hope this question doesn't sound too ambiguous despite that I have 2 questions...

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically search, or just use a GUI? Eclipse's file search gui does the latter perfectly well.

Comment: no GUI at this moment. Just 'programmatically' search.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I use the GUI search feature?

Search → File... or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>.

[image]

You can filter using a file name pattern in the "File name patterns" input field.

Comment: I just checked it out... how can I find a file in a certain project folder? I see the option of doing it in the workspace, but not in a project folder..

Comment: In the project explorer, before opening the search dialog, click on the folder you want to search within. Then, in the search dialog, choose the "selected resources" option.

Comment: Also, I just found out that opens a tab in eclipse, what I need in my program is have a way to check whether some files that I previously created exist or not. I don't know how could I retrieve data from this Search tab.

Comment: Also, I just found that the search is only done on files created in eclipse. Files that were created by the program are not registered by eclipse and normally the search feature won't work on them.
I have a few .csv files that my program creates and eclipse can't find them.

Answer (score 1):

The current directory is '.' (the dot). Do you want to search all subdirectories recursively, or are the file you want in a single directory? In the latter case a new File("./subdir").list() suffices. Also, do you want them packaged with your class files? If yes, consider putting them in a package and use this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResources().

Comment: I just want the files in a single directory. This single directory would be the current one which would be project directory.
So basically from what you told me I am thinking of doing something like: File("./").list()
Would that be alright?